# Avoid local optima training XOR

Tags: javascript, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm using **[Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic)** to train a neural network that solves an XOR with a genetic algorithm. The fitness is defined as follows:

```
// max score = 0
score -= Math.abs(0 - network.activate([0, 0])) * 5000;
score -= Math.abs(1 - network.activate([1, 0])) * 5000;
score -= Math.abs(1 - network.activate([0, 1])) * 5000;
score -= Math.abs(0 - network.activate([1, 1])) * 5000;
```

Sometimes it runs just fine. But i'm assuming it just lucked out then. But quite often, it won't even reach `-6000`. It will hang around `-8000` a lot.

These are my settings:

```
  GNN = new Evolution({
    size: 100,
    elitism: 10,
    mutationRate: 0.3,
    networkSize : [2,3,1],
    mutationMethod: [
      Methods.Mutate.MODIFY_RANDOM_BIAS,
      Methods.Mutate.MODIFY_RANDOM_WEIGHT,
      Methods.Mutate.SWAP_BIAS,
      Methods.Mutate.SWAP_WEIGHT,
      Methods.Mutate.MODIFY_SQUASH
    ],
    crossOverMethod: [
      Methods.Crossover.UNIFORM,
      Methods.Crossover.AVERAGE,
      Methods.Crossover.SINGLE_POINT,
      Methods.Crossover.TWO_POINT
    ],
    selectionMethod: [
      Methods.Selection.FITNESS_PROPORTIONATE
    ],
    generationMethod: [
      Methods.Generation.POINTS
    ],
    fitnessFunction: function(network){
      var score = 0;

      score -= Math.abs(0 - network.activate([0, 0])) * 5000;
      score -= Math.abs(1 - network.activate([1, 0])) * 5000;
      score -= Math.abs(1 - network.activate([0, 1])) * 5000;
      score -= Math.abs(0 - network.activate([1, 1])) * 5000;

      return Math.round(score);
    }
  });
```

[(view the JSFiddle here and press train)](https://jsfiddle.net/yv39abyu/4/)

What settings do you advise me to change? (please provide with proof)

*P.S. I understand that training an XOR is much easier through backpropagation, but this is just for experimental purposes.*

Comment: I do this task in the past. GA find "good solution". So, how network topology is used?

Comment: I already improved it https://wagenaartje.github.io/gynaptic/examples/xor/

Comment: I don't understand why average fitness can be worse from previous generation continually. Do you using some super drastic premature convergence restriction?

Comment: @viceriel it has a high mutation rate and no elitism

Comment: If you have high mutation, GA acts like random search. I understand, but selection task is choose the more suitable solutions, so even without elitism I expected better average fitness in new generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed:

```
fitnessFunction: function(network){
  var score = 0;

  score -= Math.abs(0 - network.activate([0, 0])) * 5000;
  score -= Math.abs(1 - network.activate([1, 0])) * 5000;
  score -= Math.abs(1 - network.activate([0, 1])) * 5000;
  score -= Math.abs(0 - network.activate([1, 1])) * 5000;

  return Math.round(score);
}
```

to

```
fitnessFunction: function(network){
  var score = 0;

  score -= Methods.Cost.MSE([0], network.activate([0, 0])) * 5000;
  score -= Methods.Cost.MSE([1], network.activate([1, 0])) * 5000;
  score -= Methods.Cost.MSE([1], network.activate([0, 1])) * 5000;
  score -= Methods.Cost.MSE([0], network.activate([1, 1])) * 5000;

  return Math.round(score);
}
```

Which is logically, as squaring the error helps to increases the chance that an output that is completely wrong changing. [Read about it here](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/evolvexor/)